# Why equals() is true after using StringBuffer.reverse?

Tags: java, equals, reverse, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

p.equals(w) is always coming true. Why ?

http://ideone.com/JqLCDi

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

       Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
       int t=s.nextInt();
       while(t-->0){
        String k=s.next();
       StringBuffer p=new StringBuffer(k);
       int c=0;

       StringBuffer w=p.reverse();

       if(p.equals(w)){
        System.out.print(p.equals(w));

       for(int i=0;i<p.length();i++)
       {
        if(p.charAt(i)=='1'||p.charAt(i)=='0'||p.charAt(i)=='8') { c++;}
       }
       }
       if(c==p.length())System.out.println("YES");
        else System.out.println("NO");

}

    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `equalsIgnoreCase()` ?

Comment: Even a correctly copied (!) and reversed buffer will always compare not equal because StringBuffer does not override equals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your if condition

```
if(p.toString().equals(p.reverse().toString()))
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you use `StringBuffer#reverse` because they both will have the same content...

Answer (score 4):

```
public synchronized StringBuffer reverse() {
super.reverse();
return this;
}
```

Reverse will reverse the String and set it in the same StringBuffer object. So it will always be the same.

So

```
p.reverse();
```

does the same thing as saying

```
p = p.reverse();
```

And then if you do

```
StringBuffer w=p.reverse();
```

`p` and `w` will pint to same object. Needless to say `equals()` will return `true`.

You can store String Objects before and after reverse operation on `StringBuffer` and then use equals() on them. `toString()` returns new String Object.

```
public synchronized String toString() {
return new String(value, 0, count);
}
```

Comment: Good catch. +1 Now you just need the solution.. :)

Comment: Yeah was just typing the solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Unlike String, StringBuffer<sup>1</sup> is a *mutable* type. True to this design, [StringBuffer.reverse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#reverse%28%29) *modifies* the original object and then returns the *same* (current) StringBuffer instance; returning the same instance allows for method-chaining:

> [reverse] causes this character sequence to be replaced by the reverse of the sequence [and returns] a reference to this [StringBuffer] object.

Thus

```
StringBuffer w=p.reverse();
```

is semantically equivalent to

```
p.reverse();          // side-effect! reverses content
StringBuffer w == p;
// w == p -> true (same object), implies w.equals(p) -> true
```

One approach to solve this is to create a [*new* StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#StringBuffer%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) instance for w, and reverse after.

```
StringBuffer w = new StringBuffer(p);
// w == p -> false, w.equals(p) -> true
p.reverse();
// w == p -> false, w.equals(p) -> false
```

If only needing a String, the same rules/logic apply - create a new object/copy of the data *before* reversing the StringBuffer.

```
String s = p.toString()
// s == p -> false, s.equals(p) -> true
p.reverse();
// s == p -> false, s.equals(p) -> false
```

While I doubt this is the actual task, consider `p.toString.equals(p.reverse())` which also follows the preceding logic.

```
boolean reversed = p.toString()    // "s", new String / data copy
                    .equals(
                       p.reverse() // "p", reverse done after copy
                     );
```

---

<sup>1</sup> StringBuffer is old, use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) going forward unless the synchronization properties are required:

> [StringBuilder] is designed for use as a drop-in replacement for StringBuffer in places where the string buffer was being used by a single threaded.. Where possible, it is recommended that this class be used in preference to StringBuffer as it will be faster under most implementations.

Comment: Even easier: just use `String current = p.toString(); String reversedContent = p.reverse().toString(); /* compare current against reversedContent */`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks, I've included the case of using `toString` as opposed to creating a new SB.